# How can I pass arguments to a Gulp task?

Tags: node.js, gulp

Say I have a task that looks something like this:

```
settings.localLESS = ["../css/*.less"];

gulp.task('compile-less-files', function(){
    gulp.src(settings.localLESS)
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(someDest));
})

gulp.watch(settings.localLESS, ['compile-less-files']).on('change', function(event) {
        ...
});
```

But I don't want to compile them all. I only want to compile the file that I pass as an argument to the task. Perhaps something like this?

```
gulp.task('compile-less-file', function(fileName){
    gulp.src(fileName)
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(someDest));
})

gulp.watch(settings.localLESS, ['compile-less-file']).on('change', function(event) {
    ...
});
```

*Update: I want to set up watchers for all source project files and to run specific tasks once any of file will be changed.*

Answer (score 0):

Try to break down your project into small partial files, then create a new file which will act as a "master" file where you can import other files. This way you can be able to choose which file to compile when you are importing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yargs` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs

```
npm install --save-dev yargs
```

**OR**

You can use node's `process.argv`

```
gulp.task('taskname', function() {
    console.log(process.argv);
});
```

Then you can pass arguments to your task like below

```
gulp taskname --option 123
```